# Class for mail can't be found because of folder naming

Tags: laravel

I have two Classes to send emails - `SendMailable` and `ClientCart`. Both work great on localhost (Mac), but on production(Ubuntu) one or another can't be found because of the naming folder.

If folder is lowercase `/app/mail/` only `SendMailable` is found, when `/app/Mail/` only `ClientCart` is found. How this can be? Where is defined the paths of these Classes?

When I leave only folder `/app/mail` I get an Error on production:

```
production.ERROR: Class 'App\Mail\ClientCart' not found {"userId":1,"email":"info@some.com","exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Class 'App\\Mail\\ClientCart' not found at /var/www/some.com/app/Http/Controllers/CartsController.php:145)
[stacktrace]
```

This is Controller from which I send:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Debugbar;
use Session;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\SendMailable;
use App\Mail\ClientCart;


class CartsController extends Controller {

    public function send() {

        \Mail::to('info@some.com')->send(new SendMailable('somevar'));

        \Mail::to('info@some.com')->send(new ClientCart('somevar'));

    }
```

Comment: Does your ClientCart have the correct capital letters? Maybe check the class name, namespace, filename and folder name.

Comment: filename is ok, classname inside of it - ok, foldername `app/mail/` is the issue to work on both classes...

Answer (score 0):

The class autoloader is case sensitive on case sensitive systems like Linux. If your folder is called `Mail`, you need to use `Mail`, not `mail`.

(`App` being in `app` is a special case defined in `composer.json`.)

Comment: Can I define `/app/mail` also as a special case, because in this way `ClientCart` Class is not found. Also not any other class I create after `SendMailable` class. No idea why...